# Wrong link for closed questions in tag listing, causing unnecessary redirect

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, hyperlinks, question-lists

See [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) for example. Currently the question at the top of the list is closed and shows up in the list with a link to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509707/best-way-to-solve-the-sorting-problem-closed". Note how `[closed]` became part of the link even though it isn't really part of the question title. So when the link is clicked it redirects to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509707/best-way-to-solve-the-sorting-problem" of course. Note that [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=best+way+to+solve+the+sorting+problem) show the same question with the correct link.

**Edit**: This also affects pages like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions and [the front page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: The referenced question is no longer at the top, but I've verified that this happens on several other closed questions on both Stackoverflow and an SE 2.0 site.  The edit seems especially important; a bug on the tag listing page is secondary to /questions.  This might even merit a title change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well spotted; this will be corrected in the next build.